# setting a class based on an angular property

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I want to do something like this

`ng-class="'notification-{{notification.severity}}' : notification.severity"`

and have the result be `<div class="notification-warn"></div>` when the notification.severity is "warn"

currently I get `<div class="notification-"></div>`

EDIT: this is an example of what I want to do
https://jsfiddle.net/flashjammin/tgt3tok2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-if="notification.severity" ng-class="'notification-{{notification.severity}}' : notification.severity == 'warn'"></div>
```

Comment: I thought about this as well, however the div needs to show on the page regardless of the notification.severity, adding the class changes the border colour depending on the severity type, and it also toggles a seperate div to show up.

Comment: then you just add ng-if="notification"

Comment: sorry, I meant regardless of the notification

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ternary operator to toggle between class.
Set the value of 'showNotification' in controller.
Set the values of notification.severity as whole

i.e. notification.severity = "notification-warn";

Controller:

```
if(notification.severity != '' || notification.severity != null){
    $scope.showNotification = true;
}
else{
    $scope.showNotification = false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div  ng-class="showNotification? 'notification' : notification.severity">
```

Comment: kinda defeats the purpose if having the severity, the severity has corresponding colours that would change the border and background colours.